# Initialization of instance variables that have not been declared

Tags: java, oop, variables, constructor, instance

I'm new to java and I'm confused by this:
UserAccount is another class
how do i initialize user in this abstract class Person

```
public abstract class Person {
private String name;
private String email;
public Person(String name, String email, UserAccount user) {
//initalize user

    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
//user?


}
public class UserAccount {
private String username;
private String password;
public UserAccount(String username, String password) {

    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? You're already receiving the `user` as an argument.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I think they mixed up the constructors in the snippet. 2nd constructor doesn't have that as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you did what is known as [Inversion of Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control), although its application in this scenario may be not the best example. When receiving a `UserAccount` as a parameter in the construct of `Person`, you may actually want to store it as a field/attribute of class `Person`:

```
public abstract class Person {
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private User user; // Add field user

    public Person(String name, String email, UserAccount user) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.user = user; // Inversion of Control: assume user is already constructed
    }
}
```

In short: you would construct the `UserAccount` before constructing the user like this:

```
// first construct the account...
UserAccount user = new UserAccount("John", "123secret321");
// ... then pass this account to a person
Person person = new Person("John", "john@doe.com", user);
```

There is, however, the possibility to let the constructor of `Person` fully handle the construction of a `UserAccount` like this:

```
    // signature has changed, pass all necessary information to Person, let it construct a UserAccount for us.
    public Person(String name, String email, String userName, String password) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.user = new UserAccount(userName, password); // construct the user with the given information
    }
```

While you cannot call the constructor of `Person` dicretly (since the class is `abstract`), the constructor gets called, when a sub-class is constructed, e.g.

```
public class FinishedPerson extends Person {
    private Date birthDate;

    public FinishedPerson(String name, String email, Date birthDate, String username, String password) {
        // call Person's constructor that, amongst other things, initializes the field user.
        super(name, email, username, password); 
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.